# HashSet и вывод элементов в консоль

Tags: java, коллекции, hashset

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<String> values = new HashSet<>();

        values.add("Ivan");
        values.add("Petr");
        values.add("Alexandr");
        values.add("Dmitriy");

        System.out.println(values);
    }
```

`[Petr, Alexandr, Ivan, Dmitriy]` вот что я получил в консоль.
Почему вышли значения таким образом, а не по порядку как в ArrayList например?

Comment: Ибо HashSet неупорядоченная коллекция, вы можете только знать, есть там элемент или нет

Comment: а почему они должны были выйти по порядку?

Comment: [Ordering of elements in Java HashSet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9345651/2881286)

Comment: открыть книжку и почитать о коллекциях неее?

Comment: ..например Хорстманн, том 1. Основы. глава 9, неее?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как указано в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

> It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

> Не гарантируется порядок обхода набора; в частности, не гарантируется, что порядок будет всегда постоянным.

Убедиться можно на примере следующего кода:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashSet<String> values = new HashSet<>();

    values.add("Ivan");
    values.add("Petr");
    values.add("Alexandr");
    values.add("Dmitriy");
    System.out.println(values);

    values.add("Petr2");
    System.out.println(values);

    values.add("Ivan2");
    System.out.println(values);
}
```

Если его [запустить](https://ideone.com/mCsW3D), можно заметить, что порядок обхода может поменяться, например, после добавления элемента.